# PyAutoGui crashes when if/then statements are included

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I had a successful trial run with PyAutoGui recently with some crude code I wrote to help me complete some repetitive, monotonous uploads I have to do regularly for my wife's business. In spite of its ugliness, it worked well.

In an attempt to refine it a bit, I began receiving error messages only after I included an if/then statement. I added the if/then statement so that it would skip over directories that were empty. I'm trying to determine what the problem is exactly. I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 10.

Here's the code (I used the time.sleep() command because some commands take a while to perform, especially the ones inside the browser):

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
master = Tk()

def Upload_All_Amelias():
    Select_Chrome()
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.listdir('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XXS') != []:  #Checks to see if the directory is empty
        XXS_Amelias()
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab'), #Selects the Next tab
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.listdir('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XS') != []:  #Checks to see if the directory is empty
        XS_Amelias()
    else:
        pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab'), #Selects the Next tab
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.listdir('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\S') != []:  #Checks to see if the directory is empty
        S_Amelias()

def Select_Chrome():
    pyautogui.hotkey('Alt', 'Tab'),  #Selects Chrome

def XXS_Amelias():
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.moveTo(1074,160),     #Moves cursor to "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(1.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'l'),  #Selects Address Bar
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.typewrite('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XXS'),         #Pastes in correct directory path
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter'),      #Hits enter to open correct directory
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000,600),     #Positions cursor in the middle of the directory window
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks in the middle of the directory window to select the window
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'a')   #Selects all
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter')       #Hits enter to upload all selected files
    time.sleep(0.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab'), #Selects the Next tab

def XS_Amelias():
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.moveTo(1074,160),     #Moves cursor to "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(1.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'l'),  #Selects Address Bar
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.typewrite('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XS'),         #Pastes in correct directory path
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter'),      #Hits enter to open correct directory
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000,600),     #Positions cursor in the middle of the directory window
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks in the middle of the directory window to select the window
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'a')   #Selects all
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter')       #Hits enter to upload all selected files
    time.sleep(0.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab'), #Selects the Next tab

def S_Amelias():
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.moveTo(1074,160),     #Moves cursor to "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks "Add Photos"
    time.sleep(1.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'l'),  #Selects Address Bar
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.typewrite('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\S'),         #Pastes in correct directory path
    time.sleep(0.2),
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter'),      #Hits enter to open correct directory
    pyautogui.moveTo(1000,600),     #Positions cursor in the middle of the directory window
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks in the middle of the directory window to select the window
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'a')   #Selects all
    time.sleep(0.2),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Enter')       #Hits enter to upload all selected files
    time.sleep(0.5),                #ZZZ
    pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'Tab'), #Selects the Next tab

button = Button(master, text = "Upload All Amelias", command=Upload_All_Amelias, height = 5, width = 20)

button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Again, everything seems to works perfectly when I call all of them without the if/then statements. But, for some reason, when I use them, it crashes.

Here is the definition of Upload_All_Amelias when the code works:

```
def Upload_All_Amelias():
    Select_Chrome()
    time.sleep(1)
    XXS_Amelias()
    time.sleep(1)
    XS_Amelias()
    time.sleep(1)
    S_Amelias()
```

Here's the error message I get when I run it with the if/then statements included:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Sam/Python Projects/UPLOAD_ALL_AMELIAS_5a.py", line 16, in Upload_All_Amelias
    XS_Amelias()
  File "C:/Users/Sam/Python Projects/UPLOAD_ALL_AMELIAS_5a.py", line 51, in XS_Amelias
    pyautogui.click(),              #Clicks "Add Photos"
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui-0.9.33-py3.4.egg\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 362, in click
    platformModule._click(x, y, 'left')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui-0.9.33-py3.4.egg\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 437, in _click
    _sendMouseEvent(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTCLICK, x, y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyautogui-0.9.33-py3.4.egg\pyautogui\_pyautogui_win.py", line 480, in _sendMouseEvent
    raise ctypes.WinError()
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 18] There are no more files.
```

One more bit of info, it gets through the first statement fine, then crashes on the second. But the sections should be identical with the exception of the directory it's calling.

I'm sorry for such a long entry. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW: `else: pass` is useless - you don't need it. Instead of `if something != []:` you can write simply `if something:`

Comment: BTW: you can use `Selenium` to control browser.

Comment: BTW: if all functions do the same then you could write only one and execute with arguments `Amelias('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\S')`,  `Amelias('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XS')`, etc. The same with `if os.listdir()` - you could use `for folder in ('D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XXS', 'D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\XS', 'D:\\Inventory\\Amelia\\X'): if os.listdir(folder):`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Actually, it shouldn't have said "pass" underneath "else". I originally had it select the next tab. I'm not sure why I changed it. I have edited the code in the post. Thanks!

Comment: I just read over your suggestions. I understand that there are certainly ways to make it more efficient and pythonic. Honestly, I hadn't given much thought to how to do it yet. So far I've been writing things crudely and then refining them down (mostly because I don't really know what I'm doing yet). Nevertheless, I'll give these a try. Thank you again.

Comment: error message looks strage because `click()` doesn't use any file so maybe try in Google `"PyAutoGUI FileNotFoundError: [WinError 18] There are no more files."` It shows some links to PyAutoGUI forum. ie. [Multiple operations gives access denied error on windows](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/45) They should know better what problem is.